# Keeping a lulav green and moist

Tags: lulav-etrog-arba-minim, how-to

What can be done to ensure that a lulav stays green and does not [dry out](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=7&daf=29b&format=pdf)?

Comment: I've [answered my own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), but I'd still like to see what other people have tried, so don't feel shy in answering!

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/8044/603

Comment: I can't imagine that one would run afoul of the Mishna after only seven days... see Tosfos, Rosh and Ritva to the aforementioned Mishna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, it helps to keep them in a **cool, dark, and dry place** -- cool and dry to avoid problems with mold (mold apparently enjoys moisture and warmth), and dark to avoid bleaching in the light.

I have never had a problem with a lulav when stored in this way, while the already passul lulavim that I used to make rings out of dried to the point of being white when left in a lit room, at room temperature after about a week.

Comment: A lulav will really dry out within a week sufficiently to be invalid?

Comment: @DoubleAA It certainly doesn't [look nice](http://www.sefaria.org/Sukkah.31a.35), but I can't say for certain about its validity for use.

Comment: Tosfos seem to think that it isn't invalid until it's so dry that it can be crumbled, but the Rosh (and Ritva) quoting the Raavad say that it's invalid when its leaves turn white. That takes a lot more than a week...

Comment: @Matt Okay....like I said before, it's more of an issue of [not looking nice](http://www.sefaria.org/Sukkah.31a.35). Did it sound like I was talking about making it passul?

Comment: Yes, by linking the Mishna/Gemara

Comment: @Matt .....? In my above comment to Double AA?